# Google Analytics Api - How to see compatible metrics and dimensions?

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

How can you see which dimensions and metrics are compatible through the Google Api? Or does this have to be a manual process?

I need to get the information that Dimensions & Metrics Explorer web page tells you about which dimensions and metrics are compatible through the api:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

When incompatible dimensions and metrics are selected the google Api give the following error:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Selected dimensions and metrics
>   cannot be queried together. [400] Errors [Message[Selected dimensions
>   and metrics cannot be queried together.] Location[ - ]
>   Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]]

This code gets a list of all the dimenions and metrics:

```
MetadataResource.ColumnsResource.ListRequest request = analyticsService.Metadata.Columns.List("ga");
Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data.Columns result = request.Execute();
```